# A different domain per language in php based project

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I recently bought few others domain names for my project.

My question is very simple..

I want to coordinate each domain name on different language in my project..

```
Language                Lauguage folder        Different domains

English                 www.mysite.com/en      www.mysite.com

Spanish (Spain)         www.mysite.com/es      www.mysite.es

German (Germany)        www.mysite.com/de      www.mysite.de
```

On this above example.. www.mysite.com coordinates with www.mysite.com/en, www.mysite.es coordinates with www.example.com/es and www.mysite.de coordinates with www.example.com/de any idea how to deal with it ?

Comment: Which way round do you want the redirect? I'm assuming that if somebody goes to www.mysite.de you want to redirect them to www.mysite.com/de/, but can you clarify please?

Comment: Just set up different VHosts with different DocumentRoots for each domain.

Comment: @Nealio .. I want to have the exactly same as you said..

Comment: if somebody goes to www.mysite.de, system redirects them to www.mysite.com/de/..

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mysite\.(es|de|pt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(es|de|pt)/ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^en/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: i tried it to access this(www.example.es/test).. but it redirects to http://www.example.es/www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./www./test.. Any idea how to deal with it..??

Comment: Ah my mistake, I fixed it. Try now.

Comment: i tried again.. (www.example.pt/test)..  http://www.example.pt/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/index.php/pt/test

Comment: As per your question you only had `/es` OR `/de` Updated my answer for `/pt` as well. Try it now.